# Linux "Top" command for Windows Powershell?

Tags: linux, powershell, ssh, display, top

I am looking for a PowerShell cmdlet that can provide similar functionality to the Linux Top app. Something that refreshes at some given interval and displays the process list with CPU % util.

I have seen scripts that list CPU % utilization in a loop but something like top would be way more handy as we have setup SSH/Powershell access for management (I still prefer a putty shell!)

Comment: This falls squarely in the http://superuser.com category of questions.

Comment: Cool -didnt realize that site even existed! (I am primarily a C# developer)

Comment: The CPU property on the Process Object is not CPU percentage it is CPU time total since process start.

Comment: Alternatively just use the Task Manager on Windows 10, which can accessed via `ctrl` + `alt` + `del` as a shortcut.

Answer (score 54):

This is a simple one-liner that will also keep the labels at the top:

```powershell
While(1) {ps | sort -des cpu | select -f 15 | ft -a; sleep 1; cls}
```

This works because formatting the table without any parameters just drawls the default table. `autosize` is used to automatically adjust the column width so all the data can fit on screen.

---

Breakdown of the shortened commands:

- `select -f`: shortcut for `-first`
- `ft`: shortcut for `Format-Table`
- `-a`: shortcut for `-autosize`
- `sleep`: defaults to using seconds

Comment: `CPU` in `ps` is number of seconds of total usage, not % CPU. So this is not so useful.

Answer (score 40):

A similar solution as others, but using `Get-Counter` instead of `Get-Process`:

```powershell
While(1) {  $p = get-counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time'; cls; $p.CounterSamples | sort -des CookedValue | select -f 15 | ft -a}
```

Sample output:

```powershell
Path                                                      InstanceName              CookedValue
----                                                      ------------              -----------
\\server_name\process(_total)\% processor time                 _total               4806.03969127454
\\server_name\process(idle)\% processor time                   idle                 1103.7573538257
\\server_name\process(program2)\% processor time               program              749.692930701698
\\server_name\process(program5)\% processor time               program              563.424255927765
\\server_name\process(program1)\% processor time               program              535.714866291973
\\server_name\process(program6)\% processor time               program              455.665518455242
\\server_name\process(program3)\% processor time               program              426.416718284128
\\server_name\process(program)\% processor time                program              395.628507577693
\\server_name\process(program4)\% processor time               program              335.591496700144
\\server_name\process(microsoftedgecp2)\% processor time       microsoftedgecp      129.310484967028
\\server_name\process(system)\% processor time                 system               80.0493478367316
\\server_name\process(chrome8)\% processor time                chrome               1.53941053532176
```

I found most of the other solutions here using `Get-Process` report the total CPU time since the start of the process, which wasn't useful on my server that stays up 24/7 where the top result was always `svchost` and `system` at millions of seconds.

- A true `top` or Task Manager equivalent would give a snapshot of the CPU usage recorded recently over some fixed time and `Get-Counter` provides that. I figured this alternative is worth contributing since this question is still the top Google result for *`powershell top`*.

---

Based on Example 13 from the `Get-Counter` [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics/Get-Counter), a breakdown of the command:

- `While(1) {`: Creates a loop
- `get-counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time'`: Selects CPU % data, which takes a significant amount of time to return, so no need to `sleep`
- `cls`: Clear for the new table
- `sort -des CookedValue`: Sort largest on top for `CookedValue` [field we're interested in]
- `select -f 15`: Display first 15
- `ft -a`: Display in formatted table

Comment: This is the best answer: `Get-Counter` gives you the "instantaneous" CPU, rather than the cumulative CPU time from `ps`. [Better formatting](https://www.penguinprompt.com/list-process-cpu-usage-windows-and-linux/):

`Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty countersamples| Select-Object -Property instancename, cookedvalue| ? {$_.instanceName -notmatch "^(idle|_total|system)$"} | Sort-Object -Property cookedvalue -Descending| Select-Object -First 25| ft InstanceName,@{L='CPU';E={($_.Cookedvalue/100/$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS).toString('P')}} -AutoSize`

Comment: I ran into issues with errors causing the command to stop before reporting all running processes. This can be avoided with:
`$p = get-counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`
As you can imagine, this will report as many processes as possible.

Comment: Best answer! The international version which works on German/French etc installations is `while(1) { $p = Get-Counter -Counter '\230(*)\6' ; clear ; $p.CounterSamples | Sort-Object -Descending CookedValue | Select-Object -First 25}` - See `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\<number>\Counter` for which number represents what.

Answer (score 30):

There's nothing that I know of that in single cmdlet form, but like you say, scripts are easy to write to emulate top.

```powershell
while (1) { ps | sort -desc cpu | select -first 30; sleep -seconds 2; cls }
```

Comment: close enough - I can tweak it from here... well, done! 

(I am a C# developer, but manage our servers too - so coming up the PowerShell curve...)

Comment: if you want to learn more - by example - check out www.poshcode.org

Comment: @TimAtVenturality - You can wrap the script as a function with parameters to more closely replicate top.

Comment: This is a very pleasant solution in terms of the sleep cycles

Answer (score 20):

You can try [`NTop`](https://github.com/Nuke928/NTop) ([binaries](https://github.com/Nuke928/NTop/releases)), an `htop` alternative for windows, with `Vi`-emulation for Windows:

[image: Screenshot]

- **Command line options**:

  - **`C`:** Use monochrome color scheme
  - **`h`:** Display help
  - **`p <PID>`:** Show only the given PIDs
  - **`s <COLUMN>`:** Sort by this column
  - **`u <USERNAME>`:** Only display processes belonging to this user
  - **`v`:** Print version
- **Interactive commands:**

  - **<kbd>↑</kbd>**, **<kbd>↓</kbd>**, **<kbd>PageUp</kbd>**, **<kbd>PageDn</kbd>**, **<kbd>j</kbd>**, **<kbd>k</kbd>:** Scroll the process list
  - **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>←</kbd>** or **<kbd>→</kbd>:** Change the process sort column
  - **<kbd>g</kbd>:** Go to the top of the process list
  - **<kbd>G</kbd>:** Go to the bottom of the process list
  - **<kbd>Space</kbd>:** Tag a selected process
  - **<kbd>U</kbd>:** Untag all tagged processes
  - **<kbd>K</kbd>:** Kill all tagged processes
  - **<kbd>I</kbd>:** Invert the sort order
  - **<kbd>F</kbd>:** Follow process 
     *If the sort order causes the currently selected process to move in the list, make the selection bar follow it (moving the cursor manually automatically disables this feature)*.
  - **<kbd>n</kbd>:** Next in search
  - **<kbd>N</kbd>:** Previous in search
- **`Vi` commands**:

  - **`:exec <command>`:** Executes the given Windows command
  - **`:kill <PIDs>`:** Kill all given processes
  - **`:q`** or **`:quit`:** Quit `NTop`
  - **`/<PATTERN>`** or **`:search <PATTERN>`:** Do a search
  - **`:sort <COLUMN>`:** Sort the process list after the given column
  - **`:tree`:** View process tree

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to accomplish the solution with this?  [from review](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/849839)  Good guidance on recommending software [here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers)

Answer (score 12):

Provides nice headings at the top with every update without needing to clear the entire console:

```powershell
$saveY = [console]::CursorTop
$saveX = [console]::CursorLeft

while ($true) {
  Get-Process | Sort -Descending CPU | Select -First 30;
  Sleep -Seconds 2;
  [console]::setcursorposition($saveX,$saveY+3)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware of a PowerShell cmdlet that provides the functionality, but here is a freeware external command that does about what you want, Mark Russinovich's `pslist` from the [Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) suite:

- `pslist` provides a list of executing processes in a configurable view
- `pslist -s` provides the sort of continuous update you want, with a default refresh rate of once per second

I prefer to use Mark's GUI Process Explorer, but `pslist` is handy for console sessions.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a slightly nicer way, as you get to see the headings up top every time:

```powershell
While (1) {
  Ps | Sort -desc cpu | Select -first 30; Sleep -seconds 2; Cls;
  Write-Host "Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName";
  Write-Host "-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------"
}
```

This is just a slightly nicer way, as you get to see the headings up top every time

Answer (score 4):

Save the following to `mytop.ps1`, within a folder in your `PATH` environment variable, then use one of the following from any PowerShell console:

- `mytop`: [Defautl] Sort by `Memory` and show the first 30 lines
- `mytop CPU 50`: Sort by 'CPU' and show the first 50 lines.
- `While(1) {$p = myTop Memory 50; cls; $p}`: Refreshes every second

```powershell
##################################################
#  Linux top equivalent in PowerShell
##################################################
if ($args[0] -eq $null) {
  $SortCol = "Memory"
} else {
  $SortCol = $args[0]
}

if ($args[1] -eq $null) {
  $Top = 30
} else {
  $Top = $args[1]
}


$LogicalProcessors = (Get-WmiObject -class Win32_processor -Property NumberOfLogicalProcessors).NumberOfLogicalProcessors;

function myTopFunc ([string]$SortCol = "Memory", [int]$Top = 30) {
  ## Check user level of PowerShell
  if (
    ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
    ).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
  )
  {
    $procTbl = get-process -IncludeUserName | select ID, Name, UserName, Description, MainWindowTitle
  } else {
    $procTbl = get-process | select ID, Name, Description, MainWindowTitle
  }

  Get-Counter `
    '\Process(*)\ID Process',`
    '\Process(*)\% Processor Time',`
    '\Process(*)\Working Set - Private'`
    -ea SilentlyContinue |
  foreach CounterSamples |
  where InstanceName -notin "_total","memory compression" |
  group { $_.Path.Split("\\")[3] } |
  foreach {
    $procIndex = [array]::indexof($procTbl.ID, [Int32]$_.Group[0].CookedValue)
    [pscustomobject]@{
      Name = $_.Group[0].InstanceName;
      ID = $_.Group[0].CookedValue;
      User = $procTbl.UserName[$procIndex]
      CPU = if($_.Group[0].InstanceName -eq "idle") {
        $_.Group[1].CookedValue / $LogicalProcessors
        } else {
        $_.Group[1].CookedValue
      };
      Memory = $_.Group[2].CookedValue / 1KB;
      Description = $procTbl.Description[$procIndex];
      Title = $procTbl.MainWindowTitle[$procIndex];
    }
  } |
  sort -des $SortCol |
  select -f $Top @(
    "Name", "ID", "User",
    @{ n = "CPU"; e = { ("{0:N1}%" -f $_.CPU) } },
    @{ n = "Memory"; e = { ("{0:N0} K" -f $_.Memory) } },
    "Description", "Title"
  ) | ft -a
}

myTopFunc -SortCol $SortCol -top $Top
```

Example output:

```powershell
Name                               ID User                         CPU   Memory       Description
----                               -- ----                         ---   ------       -----------
sqlservr                         7776 NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER       0.0%  19,001,488 K SQL Server Windows NT - 64 Bit
python                          12872 NA\user1                     0.0%  2,159,796 K  Python
svchost                          3328 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM          1.6%  1,022,080 K  Host Process for Windows Services
onedrive                        11872 NA\user1                     0.0%  423,396 K    Microsoft OneDrive
python                          13764 NA\user1                     0.0%  304,608 K    Python
chrome                          21188 NA\user1                     0.0%  250,624 K    Google Chrome
python                          28144 NA\user2                     0.0%  225,824 K    Python
code                            21384 NA\user1                     0.0%  211,160 K    Visual Studio Code
code                            27412 NA\user2                     0.0%  185,892 K    Visual Studio Code
ssms                            18288 NA\user1                     29.5% 155,452 K    SSMS
chrome                           7536 NA\user1                     0.0%  154,124 K    Google Chrome
code                            21652 NA\user1                     0.0%  149,900 K    Visual Studio Code
explorer                         3204 NA\user1                     0.0%  134,340 K    Windows Explorer
python                          11712 NA\user1                     0.0%  130,624 K    Python
chrome                          21588 NA\user1                     0.0%  107,448 K    Google Chrome
code                            10152 NA\user1                     0.0%  100,880 K    Visual Studio Code
code                            20232 NA\user2                     0.0%  99,124 K     Visual Studio Code
python                          22184 NA\user1                     0.0%  94,800 K     Python
code                            14828 NA\user1                     0.0%  84,872 K     Visual Studio Code
searchui                        13344 NA\user1                     0.0%  78,260 K     Search and Cortana application
com.docker.service              10644 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM          0.0%  77,332 K     Docker.Service
```

Additional credit to answers from [rokumaru](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55698377/5060792), [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55680398/5060792), and [DBADon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55697007/5060792)

Comment: It seems to be broken in my machine, there is no output. I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote [`wttop`](https://github.com/jchomarat/wttop), a `top` for the new Windows Terminal that can be launched via Powershell.

Answer (score 2):

This may also do the trick:

```powershell
function htopish {
  Param (
  [Parameter(Position=1)] [Alias("l")]
  [int]$TotalList=24,
  [Parameter(Position=2)] [Alias("r")]
  [int]$Invertal=1
  )
  Begin {}
  Process {
    While ($true) {
      $CounterSamples = Get-Counter '\Process(*)\ID Process','\Process(*)\% Processor Time','\Process(*)\Working Set' | Select-Object -Expand CounterSamples
      Clear-Host
      $CounterSamples | Group-Object { Split-Path $_.Path } | Where-Object {$_.Group[1].InstanceName -notmatch "^Idle|_Total|System$"} | Sort-Object -Property {$_.Group[1].CookedValue} -Descending | Select-Object -First $TotalList | Format-Table @{Name="ProcessId";Expression={$_.Group[0].CookedValue}},@{Name="ProcessorUsage";Expression={[System.Math]::Round($_.Group[1].CookedValue/100/$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS,4)}},@{Name="ProcessName";Expression={$_.Group[1].InstanceName}},@{Name="WorkingSet";Expression={[System.Math]::Round($_.Group[2].CookedValue/1MB,4)}}
    Sleep -Seconds $Invertal
  }
  }
  End {}
}
```

- `Function` relies on the `Get-Counter` samples and will output the `ProcessId`,`ProcessName`, `ProcessorUsage`, and `WorkingSet`.
- This counter sample could be further enhanced to include `User` and `CommandLine` in the output, but I haven't yet worked out a performant way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I want to point out that if you would like a Linux-like environment for Windows you can use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), as it brings a Linux-like environment to Windows, where you can use almost every command.

Answer (score 1):

This [comment](https://superuser.com/a/770455/989044) from Mark should get more recommendation because it does almost exactly what the question was and it works:

- > Provides the nice headings at the top with every update without needing to clear the entire console.

  ```powershell
  $saveY = [console]::CursorTop
  $saveX = [console]::CursorLeft      

  while ($true) {
    Get-Process | Sort -Descending CPU | Select -First 30;
    Sleep -Seconds 2;
    [console]::setcursorposition($saveX,$saveY+3)
  }
  ```

Comment: Except Get-Process doesn't give you a snapshot of CPU, it's cumulative.

Answer (score 1):

#### [Glances](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances)

- Win, Linux supported, high CPU consumption
- Win over SSH supported
- Win - not supported window resize
- REST API supported
- Standalone / Client / Web server modes supported
- Cygwin not supported

[image: Glances example in Windows over SSH]

#### Installation with Chocolatey

```
choco install pip
pip install windows-curses
pip install glances
```

or (if cannot find pip)

```
choco install python
c:\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe install windows-curses
c:\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe install glances
```

Run

```
C:\Python310\Scripts\glances.exe
```

#### Usage

Discover [documentation](https://glances.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) please.

Answer (score 0):

To run `top` directly from `cmd`, you'll need to create `%WinDir%\top.bat` with this code:

```powershell
@echo off

Cls && @echo TOP Program initialisation. Please Wait...

Powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -command "& {
  Cls
  While(1) { Ps | Sort -des CPU | Select -f 35 | Ft -a; sleep 2; Cls }
}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to filter by process, use `findstr`:

```powershell
while (1) { Ps |Findstr explorer | Sort -desc cpu | Select -first 30; Sleep -seconds 2; Cls }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to launch resource monitor from Powershell via `resmon`, which can be closed via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, switching focus back to the Powershell terminal.

Comment: OP would like to use remote powershell sessions, so a GUI answer doesn't fit here.

Answer (score 0):

Something else to look at is [SysInternals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-utilities)

- These are command-line tools to dump all processes, along with Process Monitor and Process Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

The below command will give the top 10 CPU utilization, with output refreshed every 5 seconds:

```powershell
while(1) {
  Ps | Sort-Object -Property CPU -Descending | Select -First 10
  Write-Host "output will be refreshed in 5 sec's `n `n Handles NPM(K) PM(K) WS(K) CPU(s) Id SI ProcessName"
  Sleep -Seconds 5
}
```